# MYSQL trigger updates all lines

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `account` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `account_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currecny` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_UNIQUE` (`account`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdO3N.jpg)

and

```
CREATE TABLE `dividends` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `stock_symbol` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `gross_amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `withholding_tax` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `net_amount` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKQsn.jpg)

and trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `balance_update_after_divi_insert` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `dividends` 
FOR EACH ROW update accounts, dividends 
SET balance = balance + NEW.net_amount
WHERE dividends.account_id = accounts.account
```

When I insert new dividend row it will update all accounts.
What is wrong with this trigger.

Comment: In words - what are you trying to do? Update both tables?

Comment: It should update only one account line balance. When I insert new dividend with account_id ("ib_usd") then it should update (new.balance = old.balance + new. net_amount) only account balance ("ib_usd"). currently it updates (sets new.balance = old.balance + new. net_amount) all account.balance (ib_eur, ib_usd and lhv_eur).

Answer (score 0):

```
update accounts
SET accounts.balance = accounts.balance + NEW.net_amount
WHERE accounts.account = NEW.account_id
```